# google map infowindow does not display correctly in fancybox

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, fancybox

I've gotten google maps working pretty well in a fancybox window. However the infowindow displays incorrectly, notice the arrow pointing to the marker is missing, the X to close it is missing and the back shadow is not correctly sized. The X can be clicked (i'm guessing its hidden in the background)

below is the image as it displays for me

[Valid XHTML http://www.tappertracker.com/ScreenShot2013-07-15.png](http://www.tappertracker.com/ScreenShot2013-07-15.png)

The function that's building this is below:

```
    if (response["resp"].length > 0) {

        frLocations = new Array();
        for ( var i = 0; i < response["resp"].length; i++) {
            var elements = new Array();

            elements[0] = response["resp"][i]["summary"];
            elements[1] =  response["resp"][i]["latitude"];
            elements[2] =  response["resp"][i]["longtitude"];
            elements[3] =  i + 1;
            elements[4] = "<h4>" + response["resp"][i]["summary"] + "</h4><p><i>" + response["resp"][i]["description"] + 
                "</i></p><p>Starting: " + String.createStringFromMysqlDateFormat(response["resp"][i]["startDate"]) + "</p>"+ 
                "<p>Ending: " + String.createStringFromMysqlDateFormat(response["resp"][i]["endDate"]) + "</p>";
            frLocations[i] = elements;                  
        }           
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom : 11,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(response["ha"]["lat"], response["ha"]["long"]),
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    if (response["resp"].length > 0) {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for( i = 0; i < frLocations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : new google.maps.LatLng(frLocations[i][1], frLocations[i][2]),
                map : map,
                title : frLocations[i][0]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(frLocations[i][4] );
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }           
    }
```

EDIT:
Fancy box code that attaches to start the pop up is

```
$("#fr-map").click(function(){
            $.fancybox({
                'href': '#fr_div',
                'afterShow': function() { 
                    getFundraisersNearMe(showFundRaisers);}
            });
            return false;
        });
```

The html

```
<div id="mapFormDiv" style="display:none">
    <div id="fr_div">
<h1>Fundraisers in your area</h1>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a css problem.

Comment: What does your fancybox code looks like?

Comment: As Geocodezip says, it's (almost undoubtedly) a CSS issue. Select all with `ctrl-A`. Do the missing element(s) show? You will need to customize the default google maps styles to prevent them from being interfered with by fancybox.

Comment: beetroot-beetroot: ctrl-a indicates that the close 'x' is there but hidden. The other items do not appear to be there.

Comment: Could you advise on the best approach to find the css issue. Though I understand it my css is not amazing and tracking this down is new to me

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. This has to do with bootstrap styles interfering with google. I solved mine using

```
/** FIX for Bootstrap and Google Maps Info window styes problem **/
img[src*="gstatic.com/"], img[src*="googleapis.com/"] {
max-width: none;
}
```

or simply

```
img {
 max-width: none;
}
```